# Plain HTML displayed instead of Captcha widget in Django?

Tags: django, recaptcha

I am using recaptcha-client from google. I signed up and get the private and public key for the localhost. 
I am sending re-captcha to the template like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from summary.captcha import displayhtml

 public_key = settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
 script = displayhtml(public_key=public_key)
return render_to_response('index.html', {'state':state, 'script':script}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This html is displayed instead of widget:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lf5Cd8SAAAAAD9TUGVAkEOHfHJWnZc9mK2lO5-W"></script> <noscript> <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lf5Cd8SAAAAAD9TUGVAkEOHfHJWnZc9mK2lO5-W" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br /> <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea> <input type='hidden' name='recaptcha_response_field' value='manual_challenge' /> </noscript>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: maybe there is something you missed to put in your codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to flag your `script` variable as safe.

In a template you do:

```
{{ script|safe }}
```